# How to read Window.Object from Script tags

Tags: javascript, same-origin-policy

So, Let's say there is some content on https://example.com/file.js and then I cross-include that url on my domain example.org such as

```
<script src="https://example.com/file.js"></script>
```

How can I read the content of `file.js` from my domain example.org which it requested from example.com ?

Is this possible using `window.Object()` ?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript loaded via a `src` attribute is not automatically made available to the JavaScript program.

To read it, you need to make a separate HTTP request to fetch it (although caching rules apply so a well-configured system will not result in a duplicate request actually being made). From JavaScript in a browser, you can do this using the `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` APIs.

Since you want to read it across origins, *example.com* will have to grant permission for *example.org* to read the data using CORS.

---

`window.Object()` is a function used to create objects. It isn't at all useful for reading the source code of JavaScript programs.

Comment: Can you access a Variable though or determine the name of a variable?